Strange Behavior with Soft Latching Power Circuit: LED Inconsistently Staying On
I'm here because I'm experiencing a very strange behavior with a Soft Latching power circuit found on YouTube.
Yesterday, after finishing my circuit and code, it was working weirdly: the LED would light up, then turn off, and then light up again instantly for 6 seconds. A few dozen minutes later, it was impossible to keep the LED on.
I decided to take my circuit to a friend's place. We started by testing a few terminals with a multimeter and, voila, it worked perfectly—the LED stayed on for 6 seconds. I went back home, set up in my living room, reconnected the battery, and everything was fine. I disconnected the battery and, 3-4 hours later, went back to my office, connected the battery, and it didn't work anymore.
Could it be interference from my big PC? I don't understand...
I added a led to OUTPUT 1 to simulate a process with my ATTiny85.
I removed the C1 because the internal capacitor of my mosfets is enought. (And because it worked good depending where i am...) And I changed the resistors with the exact value i need (calculated with CISS)
Here is an image of the circuit i found.

Here is my setup (sorry, I did my best):

And a video (with my old version (long câbles)):
https://streamable.com/r4cf9j
My code:
int stay = 2;
int led = 1;

void setup() {
  // Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(stay, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); 
  digitalWrite(stay, 1);
  digitalWrite(led, 1); 
}

void loop() {
    delay(6000);
    digitalWrite(stay, 0); 
}

My specifications:

Lipo 3.7v
ATTiny85
P-channel MOSFET TO-2305:

Condition: VDS=VGS, ID=-250uA
Min: -0.45V
Max: -1.5V
Ciss: 1200


N-channel MOSFET TO-2302:

Condition: VDS=VGS, ID=-250uA
Min: 0.4V
Max: 1V
Ciss: 300


R1: 820 ohms
R2: 3.3k ohms

Thanks for your help.

None of the resistors match the schematic.  There is no LED on the schematic.  There is no power supply decoupling for the uC.  There are no pin assignments for the uC.

Hey @AnalogKid I calculated the exact résistors for my mosfets with the CISS of each. For the pin assignments, check my code, and for the power supply, i have a Lipo 3.7v without capacitors because I'm using the internal capacitor of mosfets

@AnalogKid check the édit.

to 2305 is not a MOSFET that I can find. Please edit the question with a link to a proper datasheet.

@RussellH edited. Just Google "MOSFET 2305 datasheet" but i put links!

Please don't delete and repost

What symptom does the circuit show when you state "went back to my office, connected the battery, and it didn't work anymore."  Are you saying that Q1 never turns on (so microprocessor has no power), or are you saying that upon releasing the momentary switch that Q1 and microprocessor turn off immediately?   The key signals you need to monitor here are the Q1 gate voltage, the VCC rail, and the microprocessor control output signal (Vout2, strange name, how about "Keep_Power_On").   Measure them when working and when not working and report observations.

Also @AnalogKid is correct that the microprocessor needs a decoupling capacitor or two (0.1uf and 1uF perhaps) between close to its VCC and Ground pins other wise the processor internal power could be unstable and microprocessor will randomly crash or reset.   This decoupling for digital circuits has nothing to do with capacitance that may or may not be helpful at the gate of Q1 for noise immunity, decoupling is necessary part of power distribution system even when directly connecting battery to microprocessor VCC.

Switch bounce is likely to cause MCU power to switch rapidly on and off, and no doubt this will wreak havoc with the reset circuitry inside the MCU. It's probably crashing. You absolutely must decouple the supply, near the MCU, and you should probably debounce the switch. The argument that the MOSFET parasitic capacitances are "enough" is ludicrous.

Switch bounce is likely to cause MCU power to switch rapidly on and off, and no doubt this will wreak havoc with the reset circuitry inside the MCU. It's probably crashing. You absolutely must decouple the supply, near the MCU, and you should probably debounce the switch.
The argument that the MOSFET parasitic capacitances are "enough" is ludicrous.
R1 is too small, passing over 4mA all the while that the MCU has power, which will drain the battery more quickly. Also, its time constant with MOSFET input capacitance is only microseconds, way too short to perform any kind of switch debouncing.
Ideally you would want MCU power supply voltage to rise cleanly, without oscillation, to give the MCU a chance to start up properly. Try this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I've added R3 and C1 to debounce switch SW1, in an attempt to prevent MOSFET Q1's gate potential from rising and falling rapidly as SW1 is closed. C1 also ensures that Q1 remains off as the battery is connected.
C2 and C3 decouple supply fluctuations from the MCU. You may only need C3, but if you still have trouble, try adding C2. Those capacitors don't just protect the MCU from supply fluctuations caused elsewhere, but also from itself, from its own internal switching current transients. Supply decoupling for digital circuitry is not optional, ever.
I also raised the value of R1 to keep its current under 1mA while the system is on.

C1 and C2 are electrolytic capacitors? Because I only have polarized electrolytic and ceramic capacitors. I will test tonight this circuit. Thanks

Hey @simon, it works perfectly, i just changed C1 to 47nF ceramic. It works better because with 100nF, sometimes i got a little bounce. Why do you chose 100nF? thanks

@Naografix Time constant R3C1 slows fall and rise of gate potential, to attenuate bounces at Q1's gate, but it also slows power-out rise time. It's a compromise between power rise time and switch action smoothing, find what works for you. I'm not a fan of this design, ideally you need hysteresis for proper debouncing. Even if you found the timing sweet-spot, it can still fail occasionally.

Try adding a short ground wire from distribution to the microprocessor GND pin with minimum length [below drawn in black], place ceramic 0.1uF capacitor across the VCC and Ground pins [as drawn in blue with wire leads shortened to just reach], and another 1.0uF ceramic from the VCC pin back to ground rail [drawn below in blue again, shorten the leads].  This will greatly improve power delivery to the digital microprocessor circuit.  Maybe your software is crashing or microprocessor is resetting due to fluctuating power internally.
  The original brown and white wires used for the microprocessor ground marked with red "x"s become redundant but can be left in circuit, as multiple parallel grounds are sometimes helpful.

Hey, i will test tonight, thanks
